# NPE on FilePart mock in Spring WebFlux at reactor.core.publisher.MonoWhen$WhenCoordinator

Tags: mockito, reactive-programming, spring-test, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I would appreciate any hints on the following problem I've encountered. While unit testing multipart file upload service method in `Spring Reactive WebFlux` app, I am getting NPE for `reactor.core.publisher.MonoWhen$WhenCoordinator` as follows

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoWhen$WhenCoordinator.subscribe(MonoWhen.java:149)
```

Complete log is listed below as well.

Test :

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class FileServiceTest2 {


@MockBean
private UploadedImageRepository uploadedImageRepository;

...

       @Test
        public void assembleImageTest() {
            UploadedImage ui1 = new UploadedImage("1", "ui1.png");
            UploadedImage ui2 = new UploadedImage("2", "ui2.png");

            FilePart filePart1 = mock(FilePart.class);
            FilePart filePart2 = mock(FilePart.class);

            given(this.uploadedImageRepository.save(ui1))
                    .willReturn(Mono.just(ui1));
            given(this.uploadedImageRepository.save(ui2))
                    .willReturn(Mono.just(ui2));
            given(this.uploadedImageRepository.findAll())
                    .willReturn(Flux.just(ui1, ui2));

            given(filePart1.filename())
                    .willReturn(ui1.getImageName());
            given(filePart1.transferTo(any()))
                    .willReturn(Mono.empty());
            given(filePart2.filename())
                    .willReturn(ui2.getImageName());
            given(filePart2.transferTo(any()))
                    .willReturn(Mono.empty());

            Flux<FilePart> files = Flux.just(filePart1, filePart2);

            StepVerifier.create(this.uploadService.createFile(files))
                    .verifyComplete();
        }
```

Under test :

```
@Service
public class UploadService {

Mono<Void> createFile(Flux<FilePart> fileParts) {
        return fileParts.flatMap(part -> {
            Mono<UploadedImage> savedToDBImage = this.uploadedImageRepository.save(
                    new UploadedImage(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), part.filename()))
                    .log("createFile-fileSavedToDB"); // NPE!

            Mono<Void> copiedFile = Mono.just(Paths.get(UPLOAD_URL, part.filename()).toFile())
                    .log("createFile-pathAssembled")
                    .doOnNext(destinationFile -> {
                        try {
                            destinationFile.createNewFile();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            throw new RuntimeException(e);
                        }
                    })
                    .log("createFile-fileAssembled")
                    .flatMap(part::transferTo)
                    .log("createFile-fileCopied");

            return Mono.when(savedToDBImage, copiedFile)
                    .log("createFile-monoWhen");
        })
                .log("createFile-flatMap")
                .then()
                .log("createFile-done");
    }
```

`UploadedImage` class (w Lombok) :

```
@Data
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class UploadedImage {

        @NonNull private String id;
        @NonNull private String imageName;

}
```

SpringData Reactive Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface UploadedImageRepository extends ReactiveCrudRepository<UploadedImage, String> {

}
```

Logs are as follows:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoWhen$WhenCoordinator.subscribe(MonoWhen.java:149)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoWhen.subscribe(MonoWhen.java:99)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoOnAssembly.subscribe(MonoOnAssembly.java:76)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoLogFuseable.subscribe(MonoLogFuseable.java:53)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3080)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(FluxFlatMap.java:372)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:198)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxArray$ArraySubscription.slowPath(FluxArray.java:118)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxArray$ArraySubscription.request(FluxArray.java:91)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxPeekFuseable.java:138)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onSubscribe(FluxFlatMap.java:332)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxPeekFuseable.java:172)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxArray.subscribe(FluxArray.java:53)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxArray.subscribe(FluxArray.java:59)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxLogFuseable.subscribe(FluxLogFuseable.java:53)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap.subscribe(FluxFlatMap.java:97)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxLog.subscribe(FluxLog.java:50)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreElements.subscribe(MonoIgnoreElements.java:37)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoLog.subscribe(MonoLog.java:51)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3080)
    at reactor.test.DefaultStepVerifierBuilder$DefaultStepVerifier.verify(DefaultStepVerifierBuilder.java:728)
    at reactor.test.DefaultStepVerifierBuilder$DefaultStepVerifier.verify(DefaultStepVerifierBuilder.java:700)
    at reactor.test.DefaultStepVerifierBuilder.verifyComplete(DefaultStepVerifierBuilder.java:566)
    at pb.sl.UploadService.createFile(FileServiceTest2.java:112)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:73)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Comment: there's a lot of code here - can you reduce this sample to isolate the error? Could you provide a complete stacktrace? You could add a `checkpoint()` operator after the `when()` to possibly get more information.

Comment: @BrianClozel Thank you. I tried to reduce sample as much as possible. It accepts FilePart(uploaded from web page) and assembles it. Everything works fine in terms of webflux when I upload file from webpage. But allegedly my test fails to mock or inject mock of FilePart, as I understand. I have added checkpoint and forced stack trace after `when()`, but there is no stack trace at all. I have updates log and stacktrace as well.

Comment: Looking at the stacktrace it seems your upload service instance is null. How do you get that instance?

Comment: Also - why do you need this to be a SpringBootTest?

Comment: Do you suggest to try @WebFluxTest? I am not testing controllers here. uploadService is autowired in test class, and it is not null in other tests (which do pass). May I know where do you see imageService instance to be null?

Comment: None of those annotations - looking at your test, you don't need to start the Spring context at all. If you'd like to test the uploadService, you could instantiate it and test it directly. Now about the issue itself, it's hard to figure out what the issue is without a repro project.

Comment: uploadService has it's own mandatory dependencies (due to constructor injection).  And I believe there is no issue with it's instance, as I have mentioned it is not null in other tests. Thank you very much. I will try to instantiate directly in static configuration class as well.

Comment: @BrianClozel I removed atSpringBootTest and added static atTestConfiguration class, provided uploadService bean directly from that configuration class, but I get the same error unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking more closely, I think you're not mocking your repository as expected, and in your test the repository call returns null.

You're not using a Mockito argument matcher but a concrete instance for the argument. Later in your service implementation, this method is called, but with a different instance. My guess is Mockito is using `equals` to check if the given matches that mock call - maybe your `UploadedImage` could be improved in that regard?

`given(this.uploadedImageRepository.save(ui1))` should be:

```
given(this.uploadedImageRepository.save(any()))
.willAnswer(invocation -> Mono.just(invocation.getArgument(0)))
```

Comment: Thank you, but this won't return Mono<UploadImage> wrapper, but return underlying UploadImage instance instead.

Comment: Thank you very much. Issue is fixed, but could you please elaborate what was wrong with approach `given(this.uploadedImageRepository.save(ui1))
                    .willReturn(Mono.just(ui1));` ?